# how to show the count of particular name? & show it page using php sql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a agent table
& where all agent details hai been display.

So along with the details i want to show count the agent name has been displayed in the table in same table.

i tried this query

Select count(name) from agent;

but it shows whole table count.

i want result to be this:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
     <td>count</td>
    </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>bhaskar</td>
     <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>amit</td>
     <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>sushant</td>
     <td>8</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

```
   2/5
```

Saurabh            4/5

bt wat i m getting is this:

```html
 <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>name</td>
         <td>count</td>
        </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td>bhaskar</td>
         <td>13</td>
        </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td>amit</td>
         <td>13</td>
        </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td>sushant</td>
         <td>13</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

so how to show particular name count in table row in php page??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(name)as count,name from agent group by name
```

**Update code**

```
 <?php $query=mysql_query("SELECT count(name) as count,phone,email,t_id,name FROM transfer WHERE agent_id='$id' group by name ORDER BY t_id DESC"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['count'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: <?php  
                                 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name,phone,email,t_id FROM `transfer` WHERE agent_id='$id' ORDER BY t_id DESC");


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

?>

Comment: <?php  
                                 
$query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT name,phone,email,t_id FROM `transfer` WHERE agent_id='$id' ORDER BY t_id DESC");


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

?>

Comment: <?php  echo $row['name'];  ?> & i m fectching data on page in php

Comment: agent id repeated id in table ?

Comment: while fetching the data the count value i m getting in php page is same for all name

Comment: example:

Name Count
bhaskar  13
ramesh   13

Comment: wat i want the display shold be bhaskar 4 ramesh 7

Comment: try this..SELECT count(name) as count,phone,email,t_id FROM transfer WHERE agent_id='$id' group by name ORDER BY t_id DESC

Comment: dont use DISTINCT ,if use aggregate function count

Comment: bt if u dont use distinct the name are getting repeated which i dont want..!!

Comment: replace is group by name check previous comment

Comment: bt i had one more doubt

Comment: field name is bankname?

Comment: thnx is solved actually in group by i was using name so i changed it..!!!
so it worked....